# how to create a smooth animated hover background following pointer

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, hover, smoothing

here's the menu i want to to something similar to it ( the red nav bar )

```
[http://www.toyota.com/avalon/#!/features][1]
```

as you move the mouse you notice that the background is following the mouse but finally centered behind the menu item not just following it.

i'm looking for an example so i can learn from it and do something similar to it because in the mentioned page i can't get the jquery script that does the job here's the ready test page

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/j55nM/][2]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: WOW, this site is so buggy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this probably

```
$('#example2 a').hover(function(e){
   var pos = $(this).position().left;
   $('img').stop().animate({left:pos}); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/j55nM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "LavaLamp" jQuery effect.

See here: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/